# After converting the external MP3 with NAudio to Unity AudioClip, the memory cannot be released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mp3, naudio, audioclip

A few days ago, I wanted to convert the external MP3 with NAudio to Unity AudioClip, but after that,the memory cannot be released! See [this](http://gad.qq.com/article/detail/25038#70243/71916) post.

I've found several places that can cause memory not to be released,
especially in "WAV wav = new WAV(data)".
It's a pity. So,now I rewrite the Unity's AudioClip with NAudio.
Any good ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that this memory is never going to be released? In which context do these objects exist? Are the gameObjects destroyed? Could you please try to answer these questions by editing your initial post?

Comment: Oh,you can just try it. See:https://github.com/superowner/moe/blob/master/README.md

Comment: just like:mp3_file->byte[]->WAV->AudioClip

Comment: I don't really have the time to try anything atm. If you want to get an answer to your question, you need to add every piece of information that helps understanding your question. I still don't really get what your question is about. So you think you found an memory leak in some 3rd party library that you use in unity? Report the Bug then. If that's not what you are trying to tell us, please add more information to your post.